# Splitting elements within a list and separate strings, then counting the length

Tags: python

If I have several lines of code, such that

```
"Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners; besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.
Be seated somewhere; and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."  
I mounted into the window- seat: gathering up my feet, I sat cross-legged, like a Turk; and, having drawn the red moreen curtain nearly close, I was shrined in double retirement.
```

and I want to split the 'string' or sentences for each line by the ";" punctuation, I would do

```
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  words_split = words.split(";")
```

However, now I would get strings of text such that,

```
["Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners', 'besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.']
[Be seated somewhere', 'and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."']  
['I mounted into the window- seat: gathering up my feet, I sat cross-legged, like a Turk', 'and, having drawn the red moreen curtain nearly close, I was shrined in double retirement.']
```

So it has now created two separate elements in this list.

How would I actually separate this list.

I know I need a 'for' loop because it needs to process through all the lines. I will need to use another 'split' method, however I have tried "\n" as well as ',' but it will not generate an answer, and the python thing says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". What would this mean?

Once I separate into separate strings, I want to calculate the length of each string, so i would do len(), etc.

Comment: please explain: `How would I actually separate this list.`, separate the list how? into what?

Comment: @depperm as in make it like ["Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners'] ['besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.'] ??

Comment: okay guys, the question for my exercise is "Your task is to find sentences which contain a semicolon, and find the number of words before and after the semicolon. Use the jane_eyre_sentences.txt, which contains an excerpt from the first chapter with complete punctuation. Your program should print out the line number, and then the number of words before and after the semicolon, separated by a semicolon. "

Comment: so a "Be seated somewhere; and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."

the program should print:


Line 2: 3;8

Comment: so far I have got: 
count = -1
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  count += 1
  if ";" in words:
    wordssplit = words.split(";")
 
    print("Line "+str(count)+":", wordssplit)

Comment: obviously in the print section, i will need to calculate the length of the words split. but that means i need to calculate the length of the string before the semicolon, and the length after

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the list of created words like this:

```
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  for sentence_part in words.split(";"):
    print(sentence_part) # will print the elements of the list
    print(len(sentence_part) # will print the length of the sentence parts
```

Alernatively if you just need the length for each of the parts:

```
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  sentence_part_lengths = [len(sentence_part) for sentence_part in words.split(";")]
```

Edit: With further information from [your second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064750/python-counting-the-length-of-a-string-by-needing-to-split-it-into-a-list-and-se).

```
for count, line in enumerate(open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt")):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  if ";" in words:
    wordssplit = words.split(";")
    number_of_words_per_split = [(x, len(x.split())) for x in wordsplit]
    print("Line {}: ".format(count), number_of_words_per_split)
```

Comment: ok, say you had a normal code of line just like, how would you then split that??? just a single line of code

  Line 1: ['"Jane, I don\'t like cavillers or questioners', ' besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.']