# Python counting the length of a string by needing to split it into a list and separating elements

Tags: python

My question involves finding sentences within a text which contain a semicolon, and finding the number of words before and after the semicolon. I understand how to split everything by the semicolon, however I get two strings, but I can't seem to count the words within the string?

The text looks like:

```
"What does Bessie say I have done?" I asked.
"Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners; besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.
Be seated somewhere; and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."  
A breakfast-room adjoined the drawing-room, I slipped in there.
It contained a bookcase: I soon possessed myself of a volume, taking care that it should be one stored with pictures.
I mounted into the window- seat: gathering up my feet, I sat cross-legged, like a Turk; and, having drawn the red moreen curtain nearly close, I was shrined in double retirement.
Folds of scarlet drapery shut in my view to the right hand; to the left were the clear panes of glass, protecting, but not separating me from the drear November day.
At intervals, while turning over the leaves of my book, I studied the aspect of that winter afternoon.
Afar, it offered a pale blank of mist and cloud; near a scene of wet lawn and storm-beat shrub, with ceaseless rain sweeping away wildly before a long and lamentable blast.
I returned to my book--Bewick's History of British Birds: the letterpress thereof I cared little for, generally speaking; and yet there were certain introductory pages that, child as I was, I could not pass quite as a blank.
They were those which treat of the haunts of sea-fowl; of "the solitary rocks and promontories" by them only inhabited of the coast of Norway, studded with isles from its southern extremity, the Lindeness, or Naze, to the North Cape--     "Where the Northern Ocean, in vast whirls,    
Boils round the naked, melancholy isles
Of farthest Thule; and the Atlantic surge
Pours in among the stormy Hebrides."
Nor could I pass unnoticed the suggestion of the bleak shores of Lapland, Siberia, Spitzbergen, Nova Zembla, Iceland, Greenland, with "the vast sweep of the Arctic Zone, and those forlorn regions of dreary space,--that reservoir of frost and snow, where firm fields of ice, the accumulation of centuries of winters, glazed in Alpine heights above heights, surround the pole, and concentre the multiplied rigours of extreme cold."  
Of these death-white realms I formed an idea of my own: shadowy, like all the half-comprehended notions that float dim through children's brains, but strangely impressive.
```

So far, I have achieved:

```
count = -1
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  words = line.strip("\n")
  count += 1
  if ";" in words:
    wordssplit = words.split(";")


    print("Line " +str(count)+ ":", wordssplit )
```

My reason for the use of the counts is that it increases by 1 after each iteration and so the sentences are labelled. I have stripped the paragraphing at end of sentences, and also have split the sentences by the semicolon IF they contain the semicolon.

SO far I have only tried to print wordssplit to see what it would give me.

```
Line 1: ['"Jane, I don\'t like cavillers or questioners', ' besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.']
Line 2: ['Be seated somewhere', ' and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."  ']
Line 5: ['I mounted into the window- seat: gathering up my feet, I sat cross-legged, like a Turk', ' and, having drawn the red moreen curtain nearly close, I was shrined in double retirement.']
Line 6: ['Folds of scarlet drapery shut in my view to the right hand', ' to the left were the clear panes of glass, protecting, but not separating me from the drear November day.']
Line 8: ['Afar, it offered a pale blank of mist and cloud', ' near a scene of wet lawn and storm-beat shrub, with ceaseless rain sweeping away wildly before a long and lamentable blast.']
Line 9: ["I returned to my book--Bewick's History of British Birds: the letterpress thereof I cared little for, generally speaking", ' and yet there were certain introductory pages that, child as I was, I could not pass quite as a blank.']
Line 10: ['They were those which treat of the haunts of sea-fowl', ' of "the solitary rocks and promontories" by them only inhabited of the coast of Norway, studded with isles from its southern extremity, the Lindeness, or Naze, to the North Cape--     "Where the Northern Ocean, in vast whirls,    ']
Line 12: ['Of farthest Thule', ' and the Atlantic surge']
```

Comment: So what's your desired output?

Comment: I think you have to use regular expression to capture words that have semicolon at the end the words that are immediately followed by semi colon but with a space. That will be more easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting elements within a list and separate strings, then counting the length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063078/splitting-elements-within-a-list-and-separate-strings-then-counting-the-length)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your purpose is, but from what I understand you just want the number of words to the left of a semi and to the right of it on each line of a file? Correct? If so, this should work for ya.

```
with open(textfile,'rt',encoding='utf-8')as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for i,e in enumerate(line.split(' ')):
            if e.endswith(';'):
                print("--> {}\nContains {} words to the left, and {} words to the right\n".format(line.strip(),i+1,len(line.strip().split(" "))-(i+1)))
```